# Fallo al abortar un hilo

Tags: c#

[image: metodo que utiliza el hilo]

Este es mi método que al intentar rellenar un dgv quiero mostrar un formulario con un gif de carga. 
Una vez rellenado el dgv quiero cerrar el hilo(lo cierro al acabar el flujo normal o también al saltar una excepción).

Al intentar ejecutar el formulario de carga (a veces) me salta excepción o funciona bien o me cierra la aplicación directamente.

[image: He leido que si capturas esa excepción y no tiene un finally la vuelve al lanzar]

[image: Cierra el programa]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! te recomiendo leer [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Algo muy importante es copiar y pegar el código en lugar de poner una imagen, para que si alguien quiere probar el código no deba volver a teclearlo de nuevo.

Comment: Por otro lado, la clase `Thread` es muy antigua y está desaconsejado su uso por su dificultad y problemática. Trata de usar `BackgroundWorker` o `Task` en su lugar.

Comment: Y por otro lado, puede que la info que estes trayendo llegue muy rapido y nunca llegue a lanzar el thread antes de tener que abortarlo.

Comment: Si el metodo OpenSplashScreen toca un control del fomulario no podras lograr lo que quieres. No se puede tocar ningun control de un fomurlario en otro hilo que no sea en el de la vista.

Comment: @Rosca Bienvenido de prefrencia que tu codigo sea texto en vez de una imagen

Comment: ya esta resuelto, he cambiado en vez de lanzar el splashscreen en un thread aparte he lanzado el metodo que recoge informacion de un servidor externo. Muchas gracias por la ayuda